# OpenCV.dll and java.library.path

Tags: java, dll, path, opencv

Required library not found: `C:\Users\ath\Desktop\KA\AuIer\AI\OpenCV.dll`: Can't find dependent libraries
Verify that the java.library.path property is correctly set and the `'\path\to\OpenCV\bin'` exists in your system PATH

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Im working in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you passing -Djava.library.path in the vm arguments?

Comment: Im working on Vista. I tried to add the path by Eclipse and also by command prompt. It does'nt work.

Comment: And what about PATH Environment Variable? Have you set it to point to the bin folder of OpenCV?

Comment: Yes. The windows PATH is set to OpenCV\bin

Comment: If you are using `-Djava.library.path` the system path is ignored!