# How to run jar outside of the ide with external lib

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, executable-jar

I got a programm which use the opencv library that run well on netbeans but when i try to run it outside of netbeans using this command:

```
java -jar RecupPhotoV1
pause
```

i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no   opencv_java300 in 
java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at recupphoto.Ihm.<init>(Ihm.java:96)
        at recupphoto.RecupPhoto.main(RecupPhoto.java:18)
```

I got the project builded into the folder dist, with jar here and opencv_300.jar in a lib folder.
My objective is to make this app runnable on other computers whithout netbeans just by lauching a .bat or a script in the same folder than my jar

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

edit:
Tried some things yesterday, i exported my project from netbeans to eclipse, followed a new tutorial with new manifest etc and i think, things are going better. Now if i execute:

```
java -jar RecupPhoto.jar
```

with this manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-class: RecupPhoto
Class-path: opencv-300.jar
```

i got a thread error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Ihm.<init>(Ihm.java:82)
        at RecupPhoto.main(RecupPhoto.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
```

Duno what can be the cause of it?

Comment: Parametrize your command line invocation with a classpath argument.

Comment: have  tried
    java -cp "lib/opencv-300.jar;." recupphoto.RecupPhotoV1.jar
pause
But don't work windows said me he couldn't find the file

Comment: You need either '../lib/opencv' or '/fullpath/lib/opencv'.

Answer (score 0):

The opencv jar must be in the classpath. You must run something like:

java -classpath /path/to/lib -jar RecupPhotoV1

Comment: java -classpath '../lib/opencv-300' -jar RecupPhotoV1
    pause
told me: Error: Unable to access jarfile RecupPhotoV1

Comment: Can you try with '../lib/opencv-300.jar'

Comment: I got same problem unable to acces jarfile

Comment: Does the jar exist, is the path correct. You should find detailed response here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910115/include-external-jar-when-running-java-jar

Comment: Okay seems to go on, now using this  " java -cp  /lib/opencv-300.jar RecupPhotoV1
pause "
i got "unable to find main class RecupPhotoV1

Comment: The manifest is there but there so i thinks it's okay? "Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_45-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/opencv-300.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: recupphoto.RecupPhoto"

Comment: The "X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build" is still annoying me, dunno what it mean

Comment: You also need the opencv DLL.

Comment: In which folder should i put it? And is there anything special to add in manifest or other places?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996724/opencv-dll-and-java-library-path

Comment: Either on your PATH, or in the path specified by -Djava.library.path if you use that option.

Comment: In netbeans project properties i specified "-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64"" Which seems to be working while i run the programm on netbeans

Comment: I still get the error about java can't find the main class, which is disapointing me, cause it's well defined in manifest

Comment: Last idea do you also add "-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64" when running the jar.

Comment: It's added into netbeans' running properties into my project, so i guess it's added

Comment: Thanks for all the help you given me so far, i added the command but still got missing main class, which is not in the D java path but in RecupPhotoV1

Comment: Sorry but I'm out of ideas. Go step by step and make sure verything is fine. Your command should look like 'java "-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64 -classpath /path/to/lib -jar RecupPhotoV1.jar"

Comment: Good choice. You are missing a jar, if your opencv jar is not packaged with your jar you need to specify a classpath like previously.

Comment: Can the classpath be relative (like "lib/opencv-300.jar")?
Still got the error if i had -cp in the bat file